# Radiusd(freeradius): User only for a special client

Tags: linux, networking, wifi, radius

Is it possible to restrict a user from the "users" file to a special client?

I try to use one radiusd server for two wifi access points but I will use one user credentials only for one access point to she/he can't connect to the other network with the same credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it by giving some check attributes(mentioned below) in the same line as your password.

```
"username" Cleartext-Password := "Password", Calling-Station-Id := "MAC of User" =, Called-Station-Id =~ "MAC of AP(mostly comes in requests, if not coming NAS maybe broken)"
```

This would restrict user to the incoming MAC address and connect to a particular AP only.